# FormatException exception in DbGeography when changing region

Tags: c#, regional-settings

What's the simplest fix?

When this code runs in Australia (where it was written) it works.

```cs
public static void CreatePointTest()
{
  double lat = -33.613869;
  double lon = 153.123456;

  var text = string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);
  // 4326 is most common coordinate system used by GPS/Maps
  var ExceptionOnThisLine = DbGeography.PointFromText(text, 4326);
}
```

When I change the region code on my computer to "French (France)" and run it, I get an exception on the return statement that appears to be number format related:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled  
_HResult=-2146232828   _message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   HResult=-2146232828   IsTransient=false   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
[snip...]
       InnerException: System.FormatException
       _HResult=-2146233033
       _message=24141: A number is expected at position 16 of the input. The input has ,613869.
       HResult=-2146233033
       IsTransient=false
       Message=24141: A number is expected at position 16 of the input. The input has ,613869.
       Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STPointFromText(SqlChars pointTaggedText, Int32 srid)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line

```
var text = string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);
```

by

```
var text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);
```

In French a `,` is used as decimal operator instead of `.`.

Comment: In the meantime, I've got it working using this, which is a similar idea. What's the benefit of doing it your way?

     var text = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat);

Comment: By definition it's culture independent and should be used if you don't want regional specific settings. But to be honest: I think it is in fact quite the same as en-US. It's just formally neutral.

Comment: OK I read into it a bit. InvariantCulture will never change. However, if at some point in the future en-US decides to format with a comma, or if someone customises the culture to use a comma, then the code would break again with my approach, so InvariantCulture is the best option in this case.